# Making a collage in PIL

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, copy-paste

I. Am. Stuck.

I have been working on this for over a week now, and I cannot seem to get my code to run correctly. I am fairly new to PIL and Python as a whole. I am trying to make a 2x3 collage of some pictures. I have my code listed below. I am trying to get my photos to fit without any access black space in the newly created collage, however when I run my code I can only get 2 pictures to be placed into the collage, instead of the 6 I want. Any suggestions would be helpful.

***CODE EDITED**

```
from PIL import Image
im= Image.open('Tulips.jpg')




out=im.convert("RGB", (
    0.412453, 0.357580, 0.180423, 0,
    0.212671, 0.715160, 0.072169, 0,
    0.019334, 0.119193, 0.950227, 0 ))
out.save("Image2" + ".jpg")

out2=im.convert("RGB", (
    0.9756324, 0.154789, 0.180423, 0,
    0.212671, 0.715160, 0.254783, 0,
    0.123456, 0.119193, 0.950227, 0 ))
out2.save("Image3" + ".jpg")



out3= im.convert("1")
out3.save("Image4"+".jpg")


out4=im.convert("RGB", (
    0.986542, 0.154789, 0.756231, 0,
    0.212671, 0.715160, 0.254783, 0,
    0.123456, 0.119193, 0.112348, 0 ))
out4.save("Image5" + ".jpg")


out5=Image.blend(im, out4, 0.5)
out5.save("Image6" + ".jpg")

listofimages=['Tulips.jpg', 'Image2.jpg', 'Image3.jpg', 'Image4.jpg', 'Image5.jpg', 'Image6.jpg']

def create_collage(width, height, listofimages):
    Picturewidth=width//3
    Pictureheight=height//2
    size=Picturewidth, Pictureheight
    new_im=Image.new('RGB', (450, 300))
    for p in listofimages:
        Image.open(p)
    for col in range(0,width):
        for row in range(0, height):
                image=Image.eval(p, lambda x: x+(col+row)/30)
                new_im.paste(p, (col,row))
                new_im.save("Collage"+".jpg")

create_collage(450,300,listofimages)
```

Comment: I. See. Bugs. 
First, # is the symbol for comment, not //.
Second, loops are wrong: i should be in range (0,a) while j in range (0,b).
Did not check the rest though

Comment: @HennadiiMadan I updated my code on my shell with the loop suggestions and it now only returns one photo in the far left side of the newly created image. I also have been trying to think of any new ways to write the code and I'm still at a loss. Any more suggestions? I can't figure it out

Comment: The first problem I see is `create_collage` isn't being called. What are `a` and `b` meant to represent? I recommend proper variable names rather than single letters.

Comment: @Nikki Please post the updated code with Hugo's suggestion incorporated

Comment: @HennadiiMadan I have updated my code variables as well as listofimages list. I now have the listofimages as what they were saved as in the first part of the code. I realized that I could not get the images to "open" unless they were saved that way. Thanks again for the suggestions

Comment: @Hugo I incorporated your suggestions and edited my code.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's some working code.

1. When you call `Image.open(p)`, that returns an Image object, so you need to store than in a variable: `im = Image.open(p)`.
2. I'm not sure what `image=Image.eval(p, lambda x: x+(col+row)/30)` is meant to do so I removed it.
3. `size` is the size of the thumbnails, but you're not using that variable. After opening the image, it should be resized to `size`.
4. I renamed Picturewidth and Pictureheight to thumbnail_width and thumbnail_height to make it clear what they are and follow Python naming conventions.
5. I also moved the number of cols and rows to variables so they can be reused without magic numbers.
6. The first loop opens each image into an `im`, thumbnails it and puts it in a list of `ims`.
7. Before the next loops we initialise `i,`x`, and`y` variables to keep track of which image we're looking at, and the x and y coordinates to paste the thumbnails into the larger canvas. They'll be updated in the next loops.
8. The first loop is for columns (`cols`), not pixels (`width`). (Also `range(0, thing)` does the same as `range(thing)`.)
9. Similarly the second loop is for rows instead of pixels. Inside this loop we paste the current image at `ims[i]` into the big `new_im` at `x, y`. These are pixel positions, not row/cols positions.
10. At the end of the inner loop, increment the `i` counter, and add `thumbnail_height` to `y`.
11. Similarly, at the end of the outer loop, and add `thumnnail_width` to `x` and reset `y` to zero.
12. You only need to save `new_im` once, after these loops have finished.
13. There's no need for concatenating `"Image2" + ".jpg"` etc., just do "Image2.jpg".

This results in something like this:

[image: Collage.jpg]

This code could be improved. For example, if you don't need them for anything else, there's no need to save the intermediate ImageX.jpg files, and rather than putting those filenames in `listofimages`, put the images directly there: `listofimages = [im, out1, out2, etc...]`, and then replace `for p in listofimages:` with `for im in listofimages:` and remove `im = Image.open(p)`.

You could also calculate some padding for the images so the blackspace is even.

```
from PIL import Image
im= Image.open('Tulips.jpg')

out=im.convert("RGB", (
    0.412453, 0.357580, 0.180423, 0,
    0.212671, 0.715160, 0.072169, 0,
    0.019334, 0.119193, 0.950227, 0 ))
out.save("Image2.jpg")

out2=im.convert("RGB", (
    0.9756324, 0.154789, 0.180423, 0,
    0.212671, 0.715160, 0.254783, 0,
    0.123456, 0.119193, 0.950227, 0 ))
out2.save("Image3.jpg")

out3= im.convert("1")
out3.save("Image4.jpg")

out4=im.convert("RGB", (
    0.986542, 0.154789, 0.756231, 0,
    0.212671, 0.715160, 0.254783, 0,
    0.123456, 0.119193, 0.112348, 0 ))
out4.save("Image5.jpg")

out5=Image.blend(im, out4, 0.5)
out5.save("Image6.jpg")

listofimages=['Tulips.jpg', 'Image2.jpg', 'Image3.jpg', 'Image4.jpg', 'Image5.jpg', 'Image6.jpg']

def create_collage(width, height, listofimages):
    cols = 3
    rows = 2
    thumbnail_width = width//cols
    thumbnail_height = height//rows
    size = thumbnail_width, thumbnail_height
    new_im = Image.new('RGB', (width, height))
    ims = []
    for p in listofimages:
        im = Image.open(p)
        im.thumbnail(size)
        ims.append(im)
    i = 0
    x = 0
    y = 0
    for col in range(cols):
        for row in range(rows):
            print(i, x, y)
            new_im.paste(ims[i], (x, y))
            i += 1
            y += thumbnail_height
        x += thumbnail_width
        y = 0

    new_im.save("Collage.jpg")

create_collage(450, 300, listofimages)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: My image shows black border in between. Any way to make it white instead?

Comment: @mango Create a new base image with white colour, instead of default black: `new_im = Image.new('RGB', (width, height), 'white')`

Comment: Thanks for this. I made an improved version [in my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73517787/3873799).

Answer (score 1):

I made a solution inspired by [@Hugo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35460517/3873799) which only requires the input list of images. The function automatically creates a grid based on the number of images input.

```py
import os
from typing import List, Tuple

from PIL import Image


def find_multiples(number : int):
    multiples = set()
    for i in range(number - 1, 1, -1):
        mod = number % i
        if mod == 0:
            tup = (i, int(number / i))
            if tup not in multiples and (tup[1], tup[0]) not in multiples:
                multiples.add(tup)
                
    if len(multiples) == 0:
        mod == number % 2
        div = number // 2
        multiples.add((2, div + mod))
        
    return list(multiples)

def get_smallest_multiples(number : int, smallest_first = True) -> Tuple[int, int]:
    multiples = find_multiples(number)
    smallest_sum = number
    index = 0
    for i, m in enumerate(multiples):
        sum = m[0] + m[1]
        if sum < smallest_sum:
            smallest_sum = sum
            index = i
            
    result = list(multiples[i])
    if smallest_first:
        result.sort()
        
    return result[0], result[1]
    

def create_collage(listofimages : List[str], n_cols : int = 0, n_rows: int = 0, 
                   thumbnail_scale : float = 1.0, thumbnail_width : int = 0, thumbnail_height : int = 0):
    
    n_cols = n_cols if n_cols >= 0 else abs(n_cols)
    n_rows = n_rows if n_rows >= 0 else abs(n_rows)
    
    if n_cols == 0 and n_rows != 0:
        n_cols = len(listofimages) // n_rows
        
    if n_rows == 0 and n_cols != 0:
        n_rows = len(listofimages) // n_cols
        
    if n_rows == 0 and n_cols == 0:
        n_cols, n_rows = get_smallest_multiples(len(listofimages))
    
    thumbnail_width = 0 if thumbnail_width == 0 or n_cols == 0 else round(thumbnail_width / n_cols)
    thumbnail_height = 0 if thumbnail_height == 0 or n_rows == 0 else round(thumbnail_height/n_rows)
    
    all_thumbnails : List[Image.Image] = []
    for p in listofimages:
        thumbnail = Image.open(p)
        if thumbnail_width * thumbnail_scale < thumbnail.width:
            thumbnail_width = round(thumbnail.width * thumbnail_scale)
        if thumbnail_height * thumbnail_scale < thumbnail.height:
            thumbnail_height = round(thumbnail.height * thumbnail_scale)
        
        thumbnail.thumbnail((thumbnail_width, thumbnail_height))
        all_thumbnails.append(thumbnail)

    new_im = Image.new('RGB', (thumbnail_width * n_cols, thumbnail_height * n_rows), 'white')
    
    i, x, y = 0, 0, 0
    for col in range(n_cols):
        for row in range(n_rows):
            if i > len(all_thumbnails) - 1:
                continue
            
            print(i, x, y)
            new_im.paste(all_thumbnails[i], (x, y))
            i += 1
            y += thumbnail_height
        x += thumbnail_width
        y = 0

    extension = os.path.splitext(listofimages[0])[1]
    if extension == "":
        extension = ".jpg"
    destination_file = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(listofimages[0]), f"Collage{extension}")
    new_im.save(destination_file)
```

Example usage:

```py
listofimages=['Tulips.jpg', 'Image2.jpg', 'Image3.jpg', 'Image4.jpg', 'Image5.jpg', 'Image6.jpg']
create_collage(listofimages)
```

In this case, because the input images are 6, the function returns a 3x2 (3 rows, 2 columns) collage of the images.

To do so, the function finds the two smallest integer multiples of the length of the input list of graphs (e.g. for 12, it returns 3 and 4 rather than 2 and 6) and creates a grid, where the first number is always the smallest of the multiples and it is taken to be the number of columns (i.e. by default the grid gets fewer columns than rows; for 12 images, you get a 4x3 matrix: 4 rows, 3 columns). This it can be customized via the `smallest_first` argument (only exposed in `get_smallest_multiples()`).
Optional arguments also allow to force a number of rows/columns.

The final image size is the sum of the sizes of the single images, but an optional `thumbnail_scale` argument allows to specify a percentage of scaling for all the thumbnails (defaults to 1.0, i.e. 100%, no scaling).

This function works well when the size of the images are all roughly the same. I have not covered more complex scenarios.